# Can baggage scanners see through an aluminum suitcase?

Tags: luggage, airport-security

For the sake of specificity, let's say the Away Aluminum Edition. But I'm asking about aluminum luggage in general.

My logic is: you have to remove a tablet or laptop. so even a relatively thin metal object is impermeable. But on the other side, logically, who would get an expensive metal suitcase to have it searched on every flight?

Comment: IIRC, I've seen the insides of my aluminum-clad Macbook come up on the scanner screens.

Comment: I _think_ the rules about removing laptops are motivated by something like the complex shapes of the inside of the computer might visually drown out the less "loud" X-ray shadows of other thing place on top of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about operating baggage scanners, not about travelling.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I do not completely agree, I believe the OP is considering their choice of luggage case, which is related to travelling. Unfortunately their premise is not on solid grounds, and the question could benefit from rewording.

Comment: @DavidRicherby so where else would you post something luggage related if  there is no baggage/luggage/suitcase forum ? Where else would you take your baggage around if you weren't traveling ? Most of the time I see inane requests for closing even tjough they are very much relavant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the scanning rules rules are motivated by psychological effects ('whatever makes the public feel more secure'), not for their efficiency - in the US alone, in average 2-3 hand guns are known to be missed per day in the scanning process.

TSA Pre, CLEAR, etc., also allow scanning with the laptops (and anything else) still inside the bags.

If you peek at the monitors, you can see the interior life of aluminium laptops (and suitcases) quite well - and it is rather complicated. So if you would carry a computer (and maybe some cables, a mouse, an adapter, a camera, and some spare batteries) and a hand gun or a bomb, it is hard to see what belongs to and is inside the computer, and what is outside and worthy looking at. Therefore, they ask to take separate various of those devices.